# HTML tag not replacing

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a piece of html with some `<br>` tags in it

```
<div id="reading-project">
<p>The next morning, as soon as the sun was up, they started on their way, 
and soon saw a beautiful green glow in the sky just before them."That must be the Emerald City," said Dorothy.<br>
As they walked on, the green glow became brighter and brighter, and it seemed that at last they were nearing the end of their travels. Yet it was afternoon before they came to the great wall that surrounded the City. 
It was high and thick and of a bright green color.<br>
In front of them, and at the end of the road of yellow brick, was a big gate, all studded with emeralds that glittered so in the sun that even the painted eyes of the Scarecrow were dazzled by their brilliancy.<br>
There was a bell beside the gate, and Dorothy pushed the button and heard a silvery tinkle sound within. 
Then the big gate swung slowly open, and they all passed through and found themselves in a high-arched room, the walls of which glistened with countless emeralds.<br>
Before them stood a little man about the same size as the Munchkins. He was clothed all in green, from his head to his feet, and even his skin was of a greenish tint.
</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace the `<br>` tags with `<p>` tags using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('reading-project').innerHTML.replace('<br>', '<p>')
```

Problem is though, this doesn't work and doesn't do a damn thing. I even tried testing it on CodePen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. `.replace()` returns the result of the function and doesn't make an inline replacement. As the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) state, "This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.". Second your code only changes one instance and to change them all you want to use a basic regex:

```
document.getElementById('reading-project').innerHTML = document.getElementById('reading-project').innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, '<p>')
```

```js
document.getElementById('reading-project').innerHTML = document.getElementById('reading-project').innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, '<p>')
```

```html
<div id="reading-project">
<p>The next morning, as soon as the sun was up, they started on their way, 
and soon saw a beautiful green glow in the sky just before them."That must be the Emerald City," said Dorothy.<br>
As they walked on, the green glow became brighter and brighter, and it seemed that at last they were nearing the end of their travels. Yet it was afternoon before they came to the great wall that surrounded the City. 
It was high and thick and of a bright green color.<br>
In front of them, and at the end of the road of yellow brick, was a big gate, all studded with emeralds that glittered so in the sun that even the painted eyes of the Scarecrow were dazzled by their brilliancy.<br>
There was a bell beside the gate, and Dorothy pushed the button and heard a silvery tinkle sound within. 
Then the big gate swung slowly open, and they all passed through and found themselves in a high-arched room, the walls of which glistened with countless emeralds.<br>
Before them stood a little man about the same size as the Munchkins. He was clothed all in green, from his head to his feet, and even his skin was of a greenish tint.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. This is great. I didn't know about that `/<br>/g` expression. Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: This is a good page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp. You can Google for JavaScript regular experssions or regexes to learn more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do